# Setting the view encapsulation per css file

Tags: angular

I need to style a select's dropdown component. I used the `panelClass` to add a class to the panel but it seems like any style I add to my style sheet for that class is ignored, unless I use ViewEncapsulation.None. However, its only one style and I don't want to turn off view encapsulation just for this one style. I seen that ::ng-deep is now deprecated so I don't want to use that. Is there any way to do this without adding the style to the main style.css file, or having to turn view encapsulation off for the whole component? Ideally it would be good if you could set the view encapsulation for a specific css file when you add it to your template.